# getting the closest containing span for contenteditable keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

<sup>(Using a recent Firefox v45 on Debian/Linux, if that matters)</sup>

I have the following elements in my web document:

```
<div id="mom_minieditcontentdiv_id" contenteditable="true">
<span id="mom$miniedit__3TnS01Ncdw7tV1" class="mom_minieditvalue_cl">°</span>
</div>
```

<sup>(actually, the DOM children of that `<div id="mom_minieditcontentdiv_id"` element are dynamically changing)</sup>

I'm typing the key <kbd>a</kbd> with the focus being after the `°` sign above. The browser is (as I am expecting) updating the DOM to:

```
 <div id="mom_minieditcontentdiv_id" contenteditable="true">
 <span id="mom$miniedit__3TnS01Ncdw7tV1" class="mom_minieditvalue_cl">°a</span>
 </div>
```

In javascript, I'm using Jquery2, with the global `var $contentdiv;` initialized at `$(document).ready` time with:

```
    $contentdiv = $('#mom_minieditcontentdiv_id');
```

and I later set event handlers :

```
$contentdiv.on('input', function(ev) {
console.log("miniedit $contentdiv=", $contentdiv, " input ev=", ev, 
            " $(this)=", $(this));
});
$($contentdiv).keypress(function(ev) {
console.log("miniedit $contentdiv=", $contentdiv, " keypress ev=", ev, 
            " $(this)=", $(this));
});
```

How can I get inside these events handlers the adjusted and edited `<span>` of `id="mom$miniedit__3TnS01Ncdw7tV1"`, that is the span actually processing the `input` or `keypress` event? Do I need to explicitly handle focus events?

<sup>(FWIW, the actual and full code is the [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015) (free software under GPLv3+ license), commit [be9a045349674d01bb9...](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/commit/be9a045349674d01bb99588a4ad7e8befd4a4cb4))</sup>

So how do I get the closest (and most inner, i.e. deepest) containing `<span>` for some keyboard (`input` or `keypress`) event handled by my contenteditable `div` (i.e. `$contentdiv`)?

The motivation is that I am trying to code some structured editor. So for every keyboard event, I need to get the innermost `<span` which is addressed by that event, i.e. which has the "focus".

Comment: you want the span inside the contenteditable ?

Comment: Yes, given a keyboard event, I want the closest and deepest `<span` containing it.

Comment: But I have a keyboard event, I just want to know which DOM element is it currently changing?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033004/keyboard-events-for-child-elements-in-a-contenteditable-div) for why the span isn't available through the event object. And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353478/attaching-keypress-and-focusout-event-to-elements-inside-contenteditable-div) for a possible solution